# HTML Table automatically starts splitting rows into new columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

My problem is that HTML table instead of displaying Rows vertically, after some rows it starts to put them into a new column automatically, in this order:

```
|Row1 | Row3 | Row4 |
|Row2 |
```

But I only need it to go vertically just in one column:

```
|Row1|
|Row2|
|Row3|...
```

Below my table's HTML code and how I am loading in data:

```
<table id="coinflip-table">
    <tbody id="coinflip-list">
    <tr>
    @if (ViewBag.CoinflipAll != null)
    {
        foreach (CoinFlip.Main.Models.CoinflipViewModel cfGames in Model.Coinflips)
        {
            <td>
            <img class="coinflip-list-avatar" src="@cfGames.User1_IconUrl" />
            @if (cfGames.Status != 0)
            {
                <span class="coinflip-vs-player">VS</span>
                <img class="coinflip-list-avatar" src="@cfGames.User2_IconUrl" />
            }
            </td>
            <td class="coinflip-list-skins">
            @if (ViewBag.WeaponBet != null)
            {
                foreach (CoinFlip.Main.Models.WeaponWebViewModel wep in ViewBag.WeaponBet)
                {
                    <img class="coinflip-list-skins-small" title="@wep.Name" src="@wep.ImageUrl">
                }
            }
            </td>
            <td>
            <span class="coinflip-value">$@cfGames.TotalValue</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            <button class="coinflip-list-action" type="button" data-toggle="modal">WATCH</button>
            </td>
     }
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I cannot seem to understand the cause of it. Is there a solution to this, just to go vertically? In JS, CSS or HTML? Or the issue can be related somewhere else?

Any help is appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried to move the <tr> tags inside the foreach loop?

Comment: as @Andy said try using tr inside and also see the final generated code in order to understand the result and fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need your table to be built vertically you have to put your foreach loop around < tr > < /tr > elements

Comment: Solution worked like a charm. Able to accept it as an answer in 7 minutes. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you need to include `<tr>` tag in loop to get row foreach list

or

if you need vertical row within a column try this!

```
<!-- Row -->
<tr>
  <!-- Column -->
  <td>
    <!-- Row Within Column -->
    <tr>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
  </td>
</tr>
```

comment below if you have any questions?